# Regex for Attached Duplicated String in PHP

Tags: php, regex

For example, I have a string like this:

```
Line 1
<br/>
<br/>
Line 2
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
Line 3
```

I need to detect and replace the duplicated and attached string like the `<br/>`'s so it will be only 1 `<br/>` instead. So the final result I expect is:

```
Line 1
<br/>
Line 2
<br/>
Line 3
```

Anyone can help me with the regex? explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: What language? When you ask about regex on SO you should nearly always specify the language you are using.

Comment: @xanatos: In PHP, question edited. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(.{3,})\\1+/s', '\\1', $string);
```

This will replace any sequence of duplicate strings of 3 chars or more.

Try it here: http://ideone.com/5ew7X

If you want to replace only the `<br/>`s:

```
preg_replace('/(<br\/>\s*){2,}/s', '\\1', $string);
```

Comment: thanks, is that possible to specify a certain string to be cleaned, for example only "<br/>" will be cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

Not the straight answer to your regex question, still consider doing it using sed; courtesy of [Eric Pement's sed one-liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt).

```
 # delete duplicate, consecutive lines from a file (emulates "uniq").
 # First line in a set of duplicate lines is kept, rest are deleted.
 sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'

 # delete duplicate, nonconsecutive lines from a file. Beware not to
 # overflow the buffer size of the hold space, or else use GNU sed.
 sed -n 'G; s/\n/&&/; /^\([ -~]*\n\).*\n\1/d; s/\n//; h; P'

 # delete all lines except duplicate lines (emulates "uniq -d").
 sed '$!N; s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\1/; t; D'
```

Comment: Sorry I don't give the information for the language I am going to use, is this possible to use with PHP?